# Trouble accessing intranet by hostname via VPN

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, intranet

We have an internal website run on a server on our LAN. The intranet site is available by browsing to either of these:

```
http://computername
http://computername.company.com
```

(the latter is manually-added DNS entry).

When connected via VPN, the `computername` version doesn't work, only the full DNS URL does. Why the difference? Is this a VPN setting or something wrong with the DNS server?

Network domain is Active Directory, server is running IIS, VPN is OpenVPN.

Comment: Does your VPN server dole out IP addresses from your primary DHCP, or from its own internal pool?  To echo @Mathias below, an internal DHCP might not be putting the correct DNS suffix on the end of the VPN client's virtual NIC (so you are actually querying `computername.vpn-users-local-lan.local` instead.  Adding the correct DHCP options to the VPN server's address pool, and prioritising the VPN client's virtual NIC over the user's physical adapter might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to resolve the address using only the `computername`, when on the internal network, because of [NetBT](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/119493). You might get another IP address assigned when you come through the VPN. NetBIOS name resolution works by broadcasting a name resolution request, and thus, only works within a subnet

Another options for single label name resolution, if you aldready have records in DNS for the FQDN, would be to add `company.com` to your clients' [DNS Suffix Search List](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275553). This way, your client will try to resolve `computername` as `computername.company.com` if it cannot resolve it with NetBT or WINS